# @ViewChild is null when using Directive Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, viewchild

I am following [this](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) tutorial on how to load components dynamically at runtime, and running into problems with my `@ViewChild` being `undefined`.

**Here is my Directive`**.

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[dynamic-event]'
})

export class EventDirective {
    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

**Component where to inject template (feed.component.html):**

```
<ng-template dynamic-event></ng-template>
```

**feed.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { Event } from '../../models/event';
import { FeedService } from '../../services/feed.service';
import { EventDirective } from '../../directives/event.directive';
import { EventComponent } from '../event.component/event.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-feed',
  templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css']
})
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit {

  //feeds
  feeds: Event[];

  //Get directive which contains ViewContainerRef
  @ViewChild(EventDirective) eventHost: EventDirective;

  constructor(private feedService: FeedService, 
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.getFeeds();
  }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.getFeeds();
  }

  getFeeds(): void {
    this.feedService
    .getFeeds()
    .subscribe(o => 
      { 
        this.feeds = o;
        this.populateFeeds();
      });
  }
  populateFeeds(): void {
    //resolve my component dynamically 
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(EventComponent);
    //get FeedComponent's ViewContainer (serves as parent viewContainer)
    let viewContainerRef = this.eventHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    if (this.feeds !== undefined || this.feeds !== null || this.feeds.entries.length !== 0){
      this.feeds.forEach(x => {
        let component = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        (<EventComponent>component.instance).event = x;
      });      
    }
  }
}
```

My `@ViewChild` is undefined, and I am not sure why.  Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my problem.

Because I was not using Angular's cli command `ng generate directive`, which would have declared my Directive in the `app.module` declarations array, I was receiving this error.

I manually added my `EventDirective`, and now it works:

Here is an example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FeedComponent,
    EventComponent,
    EventDirective 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [], 
  entryComponents: [EventComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you wont be able to do that without actual native HTML element.

To verify, try it with `<div dynamic-event></div>`

`ng-template` is virtual element and is not placed inside generated HTML markup untill used (somewhere) - so as there is no element with directive, field is undefined.

Comment: My feed.component.html now looks like this: <p>Dynamic events loaded here</p>
<div>
    <ng-template dynamic-event></ng-template>
</div>
Unfortunately the @ViewChild is still undefined

Comment: to be more accurate,[ng-template](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template) itself will end up commented in html unless it is referred in an ngIf

Comment: @monstertjie_za point is set the directive on an html element like `div`

Comment: @SurajRao didnt know that. Are you sure this will happen in production build? Maybe its just in dev mode?

Comment: @Antoniossss I tried <div dynamic-event></div>, did not solve the problem

Comment: Still undefined?? Can you please create stackblitz to reproduce that ?

Comment: think there will be an empty comment

Comment: Here you can see I injected my custom directive. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftvw6m?file=app%2Finput-errors-example.html

Comment: @Antoniossss Your answer above is not correct.  I got it working with only <ng-template dynamic-event></ng-template> as my html template